# iOS scope bar font SIZE?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have implemented a search bar in my UITableview.  I have also added a scope bar.  However, the words that I am placing in the titles of the five different titles, don't fit.  I looked on the Dev center to read the docs and have only come up with,

```
scopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributesForState:
```

This method will allow you to change the font, text color, text shadow color, and text shadow offset.  But that is it, no font size.  I even tried to write,

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles.font.size
```

Of course that just does not work!  Does anyone know of a way to make a smaller font so that the words appear in their entirety?

Or.. does this just not exists and I must choose shorter words?  Thanks for any insight you may have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use

```
[self.searchBar setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:15], NSFontAttributeName, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Wow, that worked great!  Where on Earth did you find that?  Thanks so much.

Comment: How could you do this in swift?

Comment: @Nils Look at my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

```
   searchBar.setScopeBarButtonTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 15.0)!], for: .normal)
```